# Clustering with rectangular-shaped clusters in python

Tags: python, data-science, cluster-computing

I have a database of 2d points, and I want to cluster them into rectangular clusters, as shown in the image below.
[image]

I want to minimize the sum of cluster surfaces, without having too much clusters.

Do you know any relevant python implementation ?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question that's specific to Python, or even programming; maybe StackOverflow isn't necessarily the best fit for this?

Comment: Indeed.
I post the answer here in python though

Comment: @random I massively disagree with the idea that clustering points in a cloud is not related to programming. I have been working with points for years, I have been programming interfaces to work with those, saying this is off-topic is like saying that transforming data in a SQL database is not related to programming.

Comment: This question is akin (with some very very light hand waving :P) to grouping data in a SQL db. I dare believe that no one would say this is not related to programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I find the solution : a kmeans clustering with chebychev distance is doing pretty well.

You can find an implementation below, with a 2d pandas dataframe `df`

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import fclusterdata 

n_clusters = 10 #To choose (elbow method, ...)

def chebychev_dist(v1, v2): 
    return max([abs(v1[i]-v2[i]) for i in range(len(v1))])

cluster_data = fclusterdata(df, t=n_clusters, criterion='maxclust', metric=chebychev_dist)

df['c'] = cluster_data

plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], c=df['c'], s=50, cmap='viridis')
```

[image]

Comment: That's pretty cool. How did you get to that solution? (you can incorporate that in your answer if you believe it is of value. I do)